# I am trying to run class with an instance in python 3.4, I watched the example but they used 2.7,

Tags: python

## class and instance should display ham and 5 on separate lines

I tried this with python 3.4

```
class Ph:
    def init (self):
        self.y=5
    def printHam(self):
        print ('ham')
x = Ph()
x.printHam()
print (x.y)
```

I keep getting this message, how can I solve it? what is happening? I assume its a difference between python 2.7 and 3.4

Thanks in advance

Wayne

Comment: What message do you get?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is not a problem of version..

`self.y` is undeclared, because the function `init` was never called. You should've named it `__init__`. Then, it would be called when the object is created.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The way of calling init is `__init__`.When you use init simply, the function will not be executed..

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with the version of Python. 2.7 and 3.4 work the same way in this regard.

The problem is that `init` should be `__init__`. As it stands it would work if you called `init` right after creating the object, like this

```
x = Ph()
x.init()
```

but a method called `__init__` is called automatically when every object comes into existence.